# Need A help to find a logical error in my code of app of DATA-STRUCTURE

Tags: ios, xcode, data-structures, data-analysis, swift4.2

I'm making iOS app on Data Structure and there is and logical error
   in the conversion of prefix-infix-postfix so I need help to find it out.

I tried to debug my code with help of add breakpoint in my code and I also try to compare with the algorithm of the prefix-infix-postfix

---

- how the app is working

---

AS Input I'm providing a string from the user first he/she has to select from two picker view like from "What*" to "What*" they what to convert.

what* = Infix **or** prefix **or** postfix

then in a text box according to "from" user enter the expression as a string then hit the button "CONVERT" and then below the button as a label user get the answer

---

- ERROR

---

ok, so this is the code for convert infix-to-prefix, infix-to-postfix, postfix-to-infix, postfix-to-prefix, prefix-to-infix and prefix-to-postfix. I got proper output for infix to prefix, infix to postfix but for others, as I hit the Convert Button as an answer shows me some this near to my answer expression but it's not true so It means there is some logical error in that part of code

Link to code: [DATASTRUCTURE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VCj1-ukZgJbn3FyiPx-qQrxB3C89Emsr/view?usp=sharing)

```
    //
//  countViewController.swift
//  DataStructure
//
//  Created by Mihir Joshi on 18/08/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Mihir Joshi. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


extension String {
    func getCharAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)]
    }
}


public struct Stack1<T> {
    fileprivate var array = [T]()

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        return array.isEmpty
    }

    public var count: Int {
        return array.count
    }

    public mutating func push(_ element: T) {
        array.append(element)
    }

    public mutating func pop() -> T? {
        return array.popLast()
    }

    public var top: T? {
        return array.last
    }
}

class countViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource , UITextFieldDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var from_lbl: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var to_lbl: UITextField!
    // @IBOutlet weak var input_txt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnconvert: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var input_Text: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer_lbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnSave: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnHistory: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ansIs: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var toPickerView: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var fromPickerView: UITextField!
    let selectpicker = ["Prefix","Infix","Postfix"]
    var sp1 = Int()
    var selected = String()
    var btn = String()
    var btn1 = String()
    var sp2 = Int()
    var msg = "Please enter valid the selection !"
    var input = String()
    var s = Stack<String>()
    // var s1 = Stack1<Character>()

    let select = UIPickerView()
    let fromselect = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sp1 = 0;

        from_lbl.inputView = fromselect
        to_lbl.inputView = select
        select.delegate = self as UIPickerViewDelegate
        select.dataSource = self as UIPickerViewDataSource
        fromselect.delegate = self as UIPickerViewDelegate
        fromselect.dataSource = self as UIPickerViewDataSource
        btnconvert.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        btnSave.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        //     btnHistory.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneCastButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donecastPicker(sender: )))
        doneCastButton.tintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 28.0/255.0, green:  28.0/255.0, blue:  28.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        toolbar.setItems([doneCastButton], animated: false)

        let toolbar2 = UIToolbar();
        toolbar2.sizeToFit()
        let doneCast2Button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(countViewController.done2castPicker));
        doneCast2Button.tintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 28.0/255.0, green:  28.0/255.0, blue:  28.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        toolbar2.setItems([doneCast2Button], animated: false)

        to_lbl.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        from_lbl.inputAccessoryView = toolbar2


    }

    @objc func donecastPicker(sender : UIBarButtonItem)
    {

        to_lbl.text = selectpicker[sp1]
        if(sp1==0)
        {
            btn = "Prefix";
        }
        if(btn == "" && btn1 == "")
        {
            btnconvert.setTitle("Convert", for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            btnconvert.setTitle("Convert \(btn) to \(btn1)", for: .normal)

        }


        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    @objc func done2castPicker()
    {

        from_lbl.text = selectpicker[sp2]
        if(btn == "" && btn1 == "")
        {
            btnconvert.setTitle("Convert", for: .normal)
        }
        else if(btn != "" && btn1 != "")
        {
            btnconvert.setTitle("Convert \(btn) to \(btn1)", for: .normal)

        }

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return selectpicker.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return selectpicker[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        selected = selectpicker[row]
        if(pickerView == select)
        {
            sp1 = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            btn = selectpicker[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        }
        else if(pickerView == fromselect)
        {
            sp2 = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)

            btn1 = selectpicker[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        }

    }

    @IBAction func errorcheck(_ sender: Any) {
        if(from_lbl.text == to_lbl.text || from_lbl.text! == "" || to_lbl.text! == "")
        {
            var msg3 = String()
            msg3 = "Please review the selection(s)"
            let errormessageshow = UIAlertController(title: "Empty Field", message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            let defaultaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:nil)
            errormessageshow.addAction(defaultaction)
            self.present(errormessageshow,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        //  let c = historyelement.object(at: fromPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) as! historyelement
        //self.txtCast.text = c.CasteName
        let h : historyelement = historyelement()
        let dh : DatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper()
        h.Answer = answer_lbl.text!
        h.Question = input_Text.text!
        h.From = to_lbl.text!
        h.to = from_lbl.text!

        if(dh.addhistory(historyelement: h))
        {
            let sucessaddmessage = UIAlertController(title: "Updated", message: "Added to History !", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            let defaultaction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler :  { (alert: UIAlertAction) in
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            })
            sucessaddmessage.addAction(defaultaction)

            self.present(sucessaddmessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }



        //    h.From = c.from

    }
    @IBAction func convert(_ sender: Any)
    {
        input = input_Text.text!

        if(from_lbl.text == to_lbl.text || from_lbl.text == "" || to_lbl.text == "" || input_Text.text == "")
        {
            var msg2 = String()
            msg2 = "There is empty field(s)"
            let errormessageshow = UIAlertController(title: "Empty Fields", message: msg2, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            let defaultaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:nil)
            errormessageshow.addAction(defaultaction)
            self.present(errormessageshow,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        //        //------------------------------- INFIX TO PREFIX-----------------------------------
        if(to_lbl.text == "Infix" && from_lbl.text == "Prefix")
        {

            var temp = String()
            // temp = infixToPostfix(exp: input)
            input = String(input.characters.reversed())

            for i in 0..<input.characters.count
            {
                if(input.getCharAtIndex(i) == "(")
                {
                    // input = input.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: ")")
                    temp = temp + ")"
                }
                else if(input.getCharAtIndex(i) == ")")
                {
                    //input = input.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "(")
                    temp = temp + "("
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = temp + String(input.getCharAtIndex(i))
                }
            }


            temp = infixToPostfix(exp: temp);
            answer_lbl.text =  String(temp.characters.reversed())

            if(answer_lbl.text != "")
            {
                btnSave.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        //        //------------------------------- INFIX TO POSTFIX -----------------------------------
        //
        if(to_lbl.text == "Infix" && from_lbl.text == "Postfix")
        {
            //
            answer_lbl.text = infixToPostfix(exp: input);

        }
        if(answer_lbl.text != "")
        {
            btnSave.isHidden = false
        }
        //
        //
        //

        //        //------------------------------- PREFIX TO INFIX -----------------------------------
        //
        if(to_lbl.text == "Prefix" && from_lbl.text == "Infix")
        {
            var temp = String()
            //            temp = prefixToPostfix(exp: input)
            //            answer_lbl.text = postfixtoInfix(exp: temp)
            input = String(input.characters.reversed())


            temp = postfixtoInfix(exp: input);

            temp = String(temp.characters.reversed())
            var temp1 : String = String()

            //   temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: ")")
            //   temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "(")
            for i in 0..<temp.characters.count
            {

                let c = temp.getCharAtIndex(i)
                if(c == "(")
                {

                    temp1 = temp1 + ")"
                    // temp = temp + ")"
                }
                else if(c == ")")
                {

                    temp1 = temp1 + "("
                }
                else
                {
                    temp1 = temp1 + String(c)
                }

            }

            answer_lbl.text =  String(temp1)
            if(answer_lbl.text != "")
            {
                btnSave.isHidden = false
            }

        }
        //------------------------------- PREFIX TO POSTFIX -----------------------------------
        //
        if(to_lbl.text == "Prefix" && from_lbl.text == "Postfix")
        {
            answer_lbl.text = prefixToPostfix(exp: input)
            if(answer_lbl.text != "")
            {
                btnSave.isHidden = false
            }
        }


        //        //------------------------------- POSTFIX TO INFIX -----------------------------------
        //
        if(to_lbl.text == "Postfix" && from_lbl.text == "Infix")
        {

            answer_lbl.text = postfixtoInfix(exp: input);
            if(answer_lbl.text != "")
            {
                btnSave.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        //------------------------------- POSTFIX TO PREFIX -----------------------------------
        if(to_lbl.text == "Postfix" && from_lbl.text == "Prefix")
        {
            answer_lbl.text = PostfixToPrefix(exp: input);
            if(answer_lbl.text != "")
            {
                btnSave.isHidden = false
            }
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    }
    func prefixToPostfix(exp : String) -> String
    {
        var result = String()
        var op1 = String()
        var op2 = String()

        for i in stride(from: exp.count-1, to: 0, by: -1)
        {
            let c : String  = String(exp.getCharAtIndex(i))
            if(Prec1(c: exp.getCharAtIndex(i)))
            {
                op1 = s.pop()!
                op2 = s.pop()!
                result = op2 + op1 + c;
                s.push(result);
            }
            else{
                s.push(String(c));

            }
        }
        while (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            result += String(s.pop()!);
        }

        return result
    }
    func Prec1 (c : Character) -> Bool
    {
        if(c == "+" || c == "-" || c == "*" || c == "/" || c == "^" || c == "%")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    func PostfixToPrefix(exp : String) -> String
    {
        var result = String()
        var op1 = String()
        var op2 = String()

        for i in stride(from: 0, to: exp.count-1, by: +1)
        {
            let c : String  = String(exp.getCharAtIndex(i))

            if(Prec1(c: exp.getCharAtIndex(i)))
            {
                op1 = s.pop()!
                op2 = s.pop()!
                result = op1 + op2 + c;
                s.push(result);
            }
            else{
                s.push(String(c));
                //log vali line baki see in java code

            }
        }


        while (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            result += String(s.pop()!);
        }
        return result



    }


    func postfixtoInfix(exp : String) -> String
    {
        var result = String()

        for i in 0..<exp.count
        {

            //    let ch = c[i]

            let c = exp.getCharAtIndex(i)
            let c1 = String(c)
            if(isOperator(c: c)){
                var b = String()

                b = String(s.pop()!);
                var a = String();

                a = String(s.pop()!)
                s.push("("+a+c1+b+")");
                print(a+c1+b)
            }
            else
            {
                s.push(c1);
            }

        }
        while (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            result += String(s.pop()!);
        }
        return result
    }
    func isOperator(c : Character) -> Bool
    {
        if(c == "+" || c == "-" || c == "*" || c == "/" || c == "^")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    func Prec(ch : String ) -> Int {
        switch(ch)
        {
        case "+":
            return 1
        case "-":
            return 1;
        case "*":
            return 2
        case "/":
            return 2;
        case "^":
            return 3;
        default:
            return -1;
        }
    }

    func  infixToPostfix(exp : String ) -> String
    {
        var result = String()
        result = "";
        let charArray = [String]()
        for i in 0..<exp.count {


            let c : String  = String(exp.getCharAtIndex(i))

            if(c>="a" && c<="z" || c>="A" && c<="Z" || c>=String(0) && c<=String(9))
            {
                result = result + String(c)
            }
            else if (c=="(")
            {
                s.push(c);
            }
            else if (c==")")
            {
                while (!s.isEmpty() && s.peek() != "(")
                {
                    result += String(s.pop()!)
                }
                if (!s.isEmpty() && s.peek() != "(")
                {
                    return "Invalid Expression"; // invalid expression
                }
                else
                {
                    s.pop();
                }
            }
            else // an operator is encountered
            {
                while (!s.isEmpty() && Prec(ch: c) <= Prec(ch: s.peek()!))
                {

                    result += String(s.pop()!);
                }
                s.push(String(c));
            }

        }
        while (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            result += String(s.pop()!);
        }



        return result
    }


    // reversedString is reversed, or empty if myString was nil


    @IBAction func checkLabelsValues(_ sender: Any) {

        // print("Hello")
        if(from_lbl.text == to_lbl.text || from_lbl.text == "" || to_lbl.text == "")
        {
            let errormessageshow = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Selection", message: "Empty Field or Same Selection", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            let defaultaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:nil)
            errormessageshow.addAction(defaultaction)
            self.present(errormessageshow,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help not only people who ask questions but also others who may have a similar question in the future.  For this reason It is best if your question is *self-contained*; Your Google Drive file may be removed at some point in the future, making your question invalid.   It also requires more work of those who want to provide an answer.  You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54604849/edit) your question to include a [MCVE] along with a clear statement of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I tried to add code in the question where they ask to "add your code" but as I paste my code it asks me re-indent my code I do that but still, they show me some error so that's why I have to do this

Comment: Ok.  You have code there now (probably too much, but it is better than none).  Can you explain what your actual problem is?  What happens or what output do you get?  What should happen or what output do you expect/want?

Comment: ok, so this is the code for convert infix to prefix, infix to postfix, postfix to infix, postfix to prefix, prefix to infix and prefix to postfix. I got proper output for infix to prefix, infix to postfix but for other not so I need help for that !

Comment: Please edit your question to explain your problem, including specific details; what input are you providing; what output are you getting?

Comment: ok sir I did that